# Want to add Superscript data to Sqlite database

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to make sqlite manager db with superscript values and data for my unit converter app in iOS sdk [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJjCB.png)

[and like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCIia.png)

Recently I found this [this site](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html) but unable to find correct one
Any help will be appreciated thanks..

How can i Store values like as above in my Sqlite3 manager database?

Here is the problem  [I Wanted to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlDgU.png)

Comment: you need to use unicode characters...

Comment: yeah..but how to use i don't know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

you want to use 20th and the th to be in superscript. First find the unicode characters of t and h.

```
t = (U+1D57)

h = (U+02B0)
```

So you pass in as String, like this: `NSString *num = @"20\u1d57\u02b0";`

To find the unicode characters, use character viewer in Mac.

Comment: Thanks lakesh but How can i able to store those values in sqlite3 db (I meant which data-type would be fit for it?)Any idea about it?

Comment: Any idea ,How to add square (like N's square) ?

Comment: for m's cube -> "mU+00B3" is not displaying original format in sqlite3 db