# How to save data superscript in SQlite iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, subscript, superscript

I have a problem as this question: [Want to add Superscript data to Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016891/want-to-add-superscript-data-to-sqlite-database)

Can you give me an example about INSERT statement. I don't know more about `<sub>` and `<sup>`, and unicode characters.

Thanks you!

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: The question that you referenced has an accepted answer, so show us what you tried! Also `<sub>` and `<sup>` is HTML markup and unrelated to Unicode, therefore it is unclear what you actually want. - Apart from that, this looks more or less like a repetition of your previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332856/how-to-add-subscript-and-superscript-in-sqlite-ios-programming and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326359/how-to-write-subscript-in-xcode-programming.

Comment: try inserting the unicodes(in character map).

Comment: Can you give me an example  about Insert statement the unicodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
NSString *num = @"20\u02b0";
     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO table_name (feild1,feild2) VALUES ('%@',' %@');",num,string2];
```